# Ajax request to current path requests `text/html` instead of `application/json`

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have two almost identical JQuery requests that I issue after the page loads, the first one requests json for the current path and the second for a different url. I was surprised to see, though, that the first request `type` is `text/html` and the second is `application/json`. I would have expected both to be `application/json`. The requests look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: window.location.pathname,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: doSomething
});

$.ajax({
  url: '/tags',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: doSomethingElse
});
```

Yet in the network tab I'm seeing:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataType: 'json'` has two main effects:

1. It causes jQuery to ignore the content-type of the document it gets back from the server and to treat it as JSON regardless
2. It sets an Accept header (for HTTP content negotiation) requesting JSON

The server *may* use [HTTP content negotiation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec12.html) to decide what to put in the response if it has different representations of the content in different formats. Most servers do not.

It looks like yours does not. It will always return HTML for the first URL and always return JSON for the second URL.

If you want your server to pay attention to the Accept header, then you have to configure it to do so (as well as providing a JSON version of the document as well as the HTML version).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like it's the rails routes side of things that isn't doing what I was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

The content type shown is the type of the response the server is sending you, not the type of request you are sending to the server.